# How to grep only the content that contains x and y?

Tags: linux, database, grep

I have 2mill lines of content and all lines look like this:
--username:orderID:email:country
I already added a -- prefix to all usernames.
What I need now is to get ONLY the usernames from the file. I think its possible with grep file starting with "--" ending with ":", but I have absolutely no idea.
So output should be:
username
Thank you all for the help.

THIS WORKED:

cut -d: -f1

Comment: Your description is quite unclear. Can you edit your post with a few extra lines of input, and the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Even without adding the prefix, you should be able to get the usernames with `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f1
```

`-d` says what the delimiter is, `-f` says which field(s) to return.

Comment: This worked, but can you explain a bit more? what is -d: and what is -f1?

Comment: @Simon: Updated with explanation. Read `man cut` for details.

Comment: So if I want to return field 1 and 2, do I say cut -d: -f1 -f2?

Comment: @Simon: Have you read the documentation? `-f1,2` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`cat YOUR_FILE | sed "s/:/\n/g" | grep "\-\-"`